# Can't send HTTP POST with custom headers to external server

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently working on an Alexa skill using AWS Lambda, and all has been working perfectly except for one thing. I can't seem to successfully POST HTTP param's / custom headers to my server. It can grab pull the information perfectly, but I cannot figure out why it is not sending the parameters / custom headers.

My code for sending a HTTP POST request looks like this :

```
function httpGetMall(latitude, longitude, callback) {

    var options = {
        host: 'myserver.com',
        path: '/path/to/script.php',
        auth: 'myAuthenticationPassword'.toString('base64'),
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {'latitude': latitude.toString(), 'longitude': longitude.toString()}
    };

    var req = http.request(options, (res) => {

        var body = '';

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            body += d;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            callback(body);
        });

    });
    req.end();

    req.on('error', (e) => {

    });
}
```

I know for a fact the function is being called correctly, as it returns the data on callback perfectly.

On my php script, I am attempting to grab the values like so :

```
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
```

I have tried manually setting the latitude and longitude inside the function to see if they were not getting passed in, but the server still never received them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you realize that POST data is not sent in headers.  It's sent as an encoded string in the body.  That's probably where your PHP is expecting to find it, but you didn't put the data in the right place when creating the POST request in node.js.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh, I didn't realize that. How would I send the data as an encoded string in the body? I am new to NodeJS and networking, so sorry if my terminology is incorrect.

Comment: I've shown you how to do it in an answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 I modified my code correctly, but I get an error whenever trying to do anything with querystring. Do I have to upload a library or something like that for it to recognize querystring? Or should it recognize it automatically?

Comment: Please look at my answer.  It shows you where `querystring` comes from.  The code is in my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I know that you have to require it, but it is still not recognizing it.

Comment: Here's the doc for it: https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html.  Without seeing your actual code and understanding exactly what the error message is, I can't really help any further.  What verson of nodejs are you using?

Comment: @jfriend00 Finally got it to work, I ended up ditching POST and went to GET instead due to server side issues on my end. But I am going to mark your answer as correct since it did work when I did a POST to httpbin.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST data is not sent in headers.  It is sent as an encoded string in the body.  In your code, you would encode it properly and then send it with `req.write()`.  There's a POST code example in the nodejs [doc for `http.request()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

Here's how you could modify your code to do it properly:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');

function httpGetMall(latitude, longitude, callback) {

    var options = {
        host: 'myserver.com',
        path: '/path/to/script.php',
        auth: 'myAuthenticationPassword'.toString('base64'),
        method: 'POST', 
    };

    var req = http.request(options, (res) => {

        var body = '';

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            body += d;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            callback(null, body);
        });

    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
        callback(e);
    });

    // format the data appropriately for the POST body
    var postData = querystring.stringify({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude});
    // write the POST body
    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
}
```

Note: You also need to add proper error handling.  Probably you should make your callback into a typical nodejs async callback that takes an error as the first argument and data as the second.  Then, you can just call `callback(err)` when you get an error and `callback(null, body)` when you get the response data.  I've modified my answer to show this also.